# Spring boot - how to exclude a directory from a live reload?

Tags: spring-boot

Documentation only says about disabling live reload. How can I exclude certain resources path from live reload?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about `spring-boot-devtools`  and not `Spring Loaded`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude

Documents on how to exclude resources from live reloads,

Example from the documentation,

```
spring.devtools.restart.exclude=static/**,public/**
```

Comment: I think it only works with full restart and it doesn't affect live reload. It works this way in my case.